# Passing a list as an index to assign values in an n-dimensional nested list

Tags: python, list, recursion, multidimensional-array

I will have nested arrays of arbitrary dimension represented as **lists** (not numpy arrays). For instance, this is a example `mylist` of dimension 4x3x2:

```
  [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
   [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
   [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
   [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

Now, given a list represending an index, how would I set the corresponding index of this list (with a length equal to the number of dimensions in `mylist`) at value? For instance, if `[2, 0, 1]` is passed to the function, how would I turn `mylist` into

```
  [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
   [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
   [[0, X], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
   [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

I tried incrementally setting a pointer (not sure if this is the right term) variable to achieve this, e.g. `res= mylist; res = res[2]; ...; res[1] = X` but this doesn't produce expected results. **Importantly, the exact dimension of `mylist` isn't known in advance**, so it just as well could have been a 4x3x2x8 array.

Comment: your question title and question description clearly say that the indexes must be present as a list. From your comments, you seem to be happy with @Fukiyel's answer that doesn't meet that requirement (the indexes are passed as individual args)t. You might want to edit your question to reflect your true requirement.

Comment: @fountainhead Is there a situation in which splatting a list won't work?

Comment: I stand corrected. That answer does meet your requirement, but the usage part could probably have been shown with a splat of an index list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Getter

Here is a function that takes in args your list and then your indexes.

```
def accessor(array: list, *indexes: int):
    return array if not len(indexes) else accessor(array[indexes[0]], *indexes[1:])
```

**Usage** :

```
print(mylist[2][0][1] is accessor(mylist, 2, 0, 1))
```

> True

---

### Setter

To be able to edit the values, here goes another function. First the list, then the value you want to put, and at which index series.

```
def replacor(array: list, value, *indexes: int):
    accessor(array, *indexes[:-1])[indexes[-1]] = value
```

**Usage** :

```
mylist = [0, 0, [[0, 0]]]
replacor(mylist, "hi !", 2, 0, 1)
print(mylist)
```

> [0, 0, [[0, 'hi !']]]

Comment: Fun fact : I needed, searched, and didn't found a way to do what you want **few days ago**, but I got some help from a friend. I can't believe I'm not the only one that searched for a way to do that.

Comment: This seems to return the value of the list in question (a functionality I'll actually need later!); is it possible to extend this to *assign* values in a list?

Comment: There you go, added !